# Sense resistance based current sensing

Tags: current-measurement

http://www.carotron.com/articles/current-sensing-circuit/

http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/appnotes/01332b.pdf

https://www.arrow.com/en/research-and-events/articles/how-to-maximize-low-side-sensing-performance

All the above article and many other articles says that in low side current sensing, if there is any short circuit is there between power supply and ground, it goes undetected. Can anyone explain me how it is detected in high side current sensing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the two in one.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fj74cK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Mmmm... I guess you do believe that a schematic is worth at least a few dozen words. ;)

Answer (score 1):

It is not uncommon for equipment to share a ground connection. Communication protocols, analog I/O, and power adapters generally do. Medical applications are one of the few exceptions. However it is rare for equipment to share a power connection.

If, due to a fault or design oversight, power finds a path of conduction through one of those external connections then current will flow through a ground that is not part of the low-side sensing circuitry.

I’ve seen this happen with USB ports in computers, when the equipment that they are connected to used the wrong kind of power adapters (e.g., a non-isolated one, when the equipment specified an isolated adapter).